# SonarQube runner throws org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, teamcity, sonarqube, sonar-runner

SonarQube runner throws org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException when I try to analyze .Net/C# project on machine where Visual Studio is not installed.

Here is the log snippet:

```
[21:51:53][Step 2/2] 16:21:53.582 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor@2f63ef53
[21:51:53][Step 2/2] 16:21:53.764 ERROR - 
[21:51:53][Step 2/2] 16:21:53.767 ERROR - Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
[21:51:53][Step 2/2] 16:21:53.767 ERROR -    at SonarQube.CSharp.CodeAnalysis.Runner.Program.Main(String[] args)
[21:51:55][Step 2/2] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[21:51:55][Step 2/2] INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
[21:51:55][Step 2/2] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[21:51:55][Step 2/2] Total time: 9.837s
[21:51:55][Step 2/2] ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
[21:51:55][Step 2/2] Final Memory: 23M/637M
[21:51:55][Step 2/2] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[21:51:55][Step 2/2] ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
[21:51:55][Step 2/2] ERROR: Caused by: The .NET analyzer failed with exit code: 255
[21:51:55][Step 2/2] ERROR: 
[21:51:55][Step 2/2] ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
[21:51:55][Step 2/2] ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[21:51:55][Step 2/2] Process exited with code 1
```

Output when running sonar-runner -e

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The .NET analyzer failed with exit code: -532462766
        at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.analyze(CSharpSensor.java:160)
        at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.analyse(CSharpSensor.java:102)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:59)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:51)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.execute(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:120)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:264)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:220)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:135)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:158)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
```

Is Visual Studio required to analyze C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio is not required to analyze C# code, however you will need a pretty recent .Net runtime ([4.5 as of writing](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+For+Non-TFS+2013+Users)).

You might also want to have a look at the [newer integration with TFS and MSBuild](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin).